# Getting the level indicators using div tag

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape text from this [web page](https://tolltariffen.toll.no/tolltariff/headings/85.01/?language=en) (click on open all levels for better understanding)
The output I'm expecting is all of the text in the table you see in a column and with a count of how many sub-levels it comprises of.

[image: Pic for reference]

The dynamic xpath I tried

```
treeView <- rawdata %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//div//p[contains(@class, "Mui")]') %>%
  html_text(trim = TRUE)
```

gives the text I require but not the indicators of how many levels (or lines) inside. Any solutions to make it possible?

**edit : [added one more pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19w5G.jpg)**

- The first text we have in this example, "Electric motors and generators (excluding generating sets)." will be zero (meaning it does not have any parent level)
- The second text; (Motors of an output not exceeding 37.5 W) has one parent, so its sublevel is 1.
- This is the same case with 3rd and 4th as well (They have only one parent so its sublevel is 1).
- Lets look at the 5th (Of an output not exceeding 750 W), it has one parent (4th text and which inturn has 1 parent). This makes the 5th text sublevel as 2. This also applies to all the text from 6th to 8th. (1 parent + 1 parent for the parent = 2)
- 9th and 10th have one parent so they have a sublevel of 1.
- 11th and 12th have one parent and the parent has one parent, so its sublevel is 2.
- 13th text (AC motors with gear or speed converters :) has 1 parent (and subsequent 2 parents). So its sublevel is 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that because the content on that website is rendered by javascript. Luckily, If you investigate the traffic on that website, you can find an API that gives you the data you need.

[image]

Then we can just

```
library(httr)
json_list <- content(GET("https://tolltariffen.toll.no/api/search/headings/85.01"))
```

To convert the list into your expected output, we need to write a simple function to recursively unpack values from that list. Something like this

```
recur_pluck <- function(x) {
  sublevel <- integer()
  text <- character()
  recur_ <- function(x) {
    text <<- c(text, trimws(gsub("<[^<>]+>", "", x$description$en)))
    if (is.null(x$headingItems)) {
      sublevel <<- c(sublevel, 1L)
      return(NULL)
    }
    sublevel <<- c(sublevel, length(x$headingItems))
    lapply(x$headingItems, recur_)
  }
  recur_(x)
  data.frame(sublevel, text)
}
```

Then we can just

```
recur_pluck(json_list)
```

which gives you

```
   sublevel                                                         text
1         6  Electric motors and generators (excluding generating sets).
2         1                     Motors of an output not exceeding 37.5 W
3         1         Universal AC/DC motors of an output exceeding 37.5 W
4         4                             Other DC motors; DC generators :
5         1                       Of an output not exceeding 750 W&nbsp;
6         1   Of an output exceeding 750 W but not exceeding 75 kW&nbsp;
7         1   Of an output exceeding 75 kW but not exceeding \n\n 375 kW
8         1                                Of an output exceeding 375 kW
9         1                                Other AC motors, single-phase
10        3                               Other AC motors, multi-phase :
11        1                       Of an output not exceeding 750 W&nbsp;
12        2  Of an output exceeding 750 W but not exceeding \n\n 75 kW :
13        2                    AC motors with gear or speed converters :
14        1         Of an output exceeding 750 W but not exceeding 15 kW
15        1         Of an output exceeding 15 kW but not exceeding 75 kW
16        3                                                      Other :
17        1        Of an output exceeding 750 W but not exceeding 7.5 kW
18        1        Of an output exceeding 7.5 kW but not exceeding 22 kW
19        1         Of an output exceeding 22 kW but not exceeding 75 kW
20        1                           Of an output exceeding 75 kW&nbsp;
21        4                                AC generators (alternators) :
22        1                            Of an output not exceeding 75 kVA
23        1 Of an output exceeding 75 kVA but not exceeding \n\n 375 kVA
24        1     Of an output exceeding 375 kVA but not exceeding 750 kVA
25        1                               Of an output exceeding 750 kVA
```

**Update**

This function gives you the sublevel in the trade domain.

```
recur_pluck <- function(x) {
  sublevel <- integer()
  text <- character()
  recur_ <- function(x, depth = 0L) {
    text <<- c(text, trimws(gsub("<[^<>]+>", "", x$description$en)))
    sublevel <<- c(sublevel, depth)
    if (is.null(x$headingItems)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    lapply(x$headingItems, recur_, depth + 1L)
  }
  recur_(x)
  data.frame(sublevel, text)
}
```

**Update 2**

```
`%||%` <- function(x, y) if (is.null(x)) y else x

recur_pluck <- function(x) {
  sublevel <- integer()
  code <- character()
  text <- character()
  recur_ <- function(x, depth = 0L) {
    text <<- c(text, trimws(gsub("<[^<>]+>", "", x$description$en)))
    sublevel <<- c(sublevel, depth)
    code <<- c(code, x$commodityCode %||% x$headingCode %||% "")
    if (is.null(x$headingItems)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    lapply(x$headingItems, recur_, depth + 1L)
  }
  recur_(x)
  data.frame(sublevel, code, text)
}
```

**Explanations**

`%||%` is a simple function that returns y if x is NULL (a.k.a. non-existent) or x otherwise. `recur_pluck` is a recursive function that traverses through every element in a list (i.e. `x`). The function can be interpreted as first defining some variables to store the data we want, then defining how to traverse (i.e. `recur_`), next traverse the list(`recur_(x)`), and finally returning these storage variables together as a dataframe.

```
recur_pluck <- function(x) {
  sublevel <- integer()
  code <- character()
  text <- character()
  recur_ <- function(x, depth = 0L) {...}
  recur_(x)
  data.frame(sublevel, code, text)
}
```

Further, `recur_` is defined as follows:

1. For each element, the function appends the target data to respective storage variables `text`, `sublevel` and `code`. We use the `%||%` function when appending data to `code` because the 8-digit code you want could have different names. That line simply translates to first getting "commodityCode", then "headingCode" if there is no "commodityCode", or just returning an empty string if nothing can be found.

   ```
    text <<- c(text, trimws(gsub("<[^<>]+>", "", x$description$en)))
    sublevel <<- c(sublevel, depth)
    code <<- c(code, x$commodityCode %||% x$headingCode %||% "")
   ```
2. It ends if there is nothing more inside the list.

   ```
    if (is.null(x$headingItems)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
   ```
3. It traverses deeper with a the depth count plus 1 if there are other `headingItems` inside.

   ```
    lapply(x$headingItems, recur_, depth + 1L)
   ```

Final output is

```
   sublevel       code                                                         text
1         0      85.01  Electric motors and generators (excluding generating sets).
2         1 85.01.1000                     Motors of an output not exceeding 37.5 W
3         1 85.01.2000         Universal AC/DC motors of an output exceeding 37.5 W
4         1                                        Other DC motors; DC generators :
5         2 85.01.3100                       Of an output not exceeding 750 W&nbsp;
6         2 85.01.3200   Of an output exceeding 750 W but not exceeding 75 kW&nbsp;
7         2 85.01.3300   Of an output exceeding 75 kW but not exceeding \n\n 375 kW
8         2 85.01.3400                                Of an output exceeding 375 kW
9         1 85.01.4000                                Other AC motors, single-phase
10        1                                          Other AC motors, multi-phase :
11        2 85.01.5100                       Of an output not exceeding 750 W&nbsp;
12        2             Of an output exceeding 750 W but not exceeding \n\n 75 kW :
13        3                               AC motors with gear or speed converters :
14        4 85.01.5201         Of an output exceeding 750 W but not exceeding 15 kW
15        4 85.01.5202         Of an output exceeding 15 kW but not exceeding 75 kW
16        3                                                                 Other :
17        4 85.01.5203        Of an output exceeding 750 W but not exceeding 7.5 kW
18        4 85.01.5204        Of an output exceeding 7.5 kW but not exceeding 22 kW
19        4 85.01.5205         Of an output exceeding 22 kW but not exceeding 75 kW
20        2 85.01.5300                           Of an output exceeding 75 kW&nbsp;
21        1                                           AC generators (alternators) :
22        2 85.01.6100                            Of an output not exceeding 75 kVA
23        2 85.01.6200 Of an output exceeding 75 kVA but not exceeding \n\n 375 kVA
24        2 85.01.6300     Of an output exceeding 375 kVA but not exceeding 750 kVA
25        2 85.01.6400                               Of an output exceeding 750 kVA
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. what does the regex "<[^<>]+>" mean ?

Comment: I use that regex to remove HTML tags but keep the content in between because `description$en` in the JSON list is always an HTML string. `<` and `>` are literal characters. `[^<>]+` means one or more characters that are not `<` or `>`. @Frodo

Comment: thanks got that part.
but looks like the sublevels are captured incorrect for few of the texts. can you tell me whats the logic you used to find it ? @ekoam

Comment: Hi @Frodo, I consider sub-levels as the number of child branches of a parent branch. For instance, I consider "Other DC motors; DC generators" having 4 sub-levels: 1) Of an output not exceeding 750 W, 2) Of an output exceeding 750 W but not exceeding 75 kW, 3)  Of an output exceeding 75 kW but not exceeding 375 kW, and 4) Of an output exceeding 375 kW, as shown on that website. However, your image tells me that it only has 2. Maybe our definitions are misaligned. Do you mind clarifying yours?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear at the beginning. It is a concept used in the trade domain. the sublevels/indents are used to find the hierarchy level of the text. 


Added the details in the OP and added a new image with the sublevels which is the expected output. Let me know if you need more info. @ekoam

Comment: Oh, I see. It's the recursion depth. Check my update. @Frodo

Comment: Great. Thank you @ekoam for the quick answer. Really appreciate it. Can you explain the function how it works ? 
Also, in the web page, we can see the 8 digit code for some of the texts. Can we extract those too for each of the texts. Earlier I planned to do this using Selenium but since you pointed out the api, everything I require is in the api feed and it is new for me,

Comment: Hi @Frodo, check my update. I hope the explanations are clear enough.

Comment: Thanks @ekoam, you have made my work a lot easier. Any guide/website where I could learn more about lapply and recursive functions?

Comment: This [website](https://techvidvan.com/tutorials/recursion-in-r/?utm_campaign=News&utm_medium=Community&utm_source=DataCamp.com) for recursive function in the context of R. Use this `?lapply` in R console if you want to know more about `lapply`. @Frodo